# Выполнение скрипта в определёное время

Tags: php, mysql, время

Приветсвую. Мне хотелось бы узнать, как можно сделать так, чтобы в какое-то определёное время (к примеру, по МСК) выполнялся определёный скрипт. К примеру, что-то добовлялось или удалялось из базы. Вопрос может быть задан весьма некоректно - но я, к сожалению, не знаю как по другому обьяснить. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну посмотрите в поиске по слову, CRON

Comment: Сапасиба :)

Answer (score 3):

Для Unix-систем есть демон cron, для Windows-систем - планировщик задач Task Scheduler.

Comment: После установки Cygwin на Windows появляется возможность работать с cron и crontab — как во всем остальном мире :)